# "Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers."

Tags: android, maps

I've looked at just about every question on here regarding this error and still haven't been able to track it down.

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cs2110_final"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.cs2110_final.TheHunt.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.cs2110_final.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cs2110_final.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cs2110_final.TheHunt"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_the_hunt" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="(API key edited out)" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my Activity code:

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

And here's the XML reference to the Map:

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

I've gone through the entire API process three times now and no luck. Every permission that needs to be put in the manifest has been, as far as I can tell (even the sneaky GPS_Services one). Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: here's the LogCat output. It's this, followed by many repetitions of "Failed to load map..."

```
04-19 13:59:03.108: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_CONCURRENT freed 252K, 6% free 7534K/7940K, paused 4ms+7ms, total 29ms
04-19 13:59:03.138: D/libEGL(26070): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
04-19 13:59:03.148: D/libEGL(26070): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
04-19 13:59:03.168: D/libEGL(26070): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
04-19 13:59:03.198: D/OpenGLRenderer(26070): Enabling debug mode 0
04-19 13:59:05.968: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_CONCURRENT freed 301K, 6% free 7654K/8108K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 21ms
04-19 13:59:06.048: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_CONCURRENT freed 216K, 5% free 7877K/8248K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 29ms
04-19 13:59:06.128: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_CONCURRENT freed 309K, 6% free 8079K/8540K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 26ms
04-19 13:59:06.128: D/dalvikvm(26070): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
04-19 13:59:06.128: D/dalvikvm(26070): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
04-19 13:59:06.128: D/dalvikvm(26070): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
04-19 13:59:06.128: D/dalvikvm(26070): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
04-19 13:59:06.198: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_CONCURRENT freed 250K, 5% free 8330K/8736K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 24ms
04-19 13:59:06.198: D/dalvikvm(26070): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
04-19 13:59:06.258: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_CONCURRENT freed 317K, 6% free 8527K/8996K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 25ms
04-19 13:59:06.258: D/dalvikvm(26070): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
04-19 13:59:06.258: D/dalvikvm(26070): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
04-19 13:59:06.378: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_CONCURRENT freed 271K, 5% free 8689K/9128K, paused 2ms+6ms, total 31ms
04-19 13:59:06.378: D/dalvikvm(26070): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
04-19 13:59:06.398: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 283K, 8% free 8558K/9260K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
04-19 13:59:06.438: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 303K, 8% free 8566K/9260K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
04-19 13:59:06.478: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 8567K/9260K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
04-19 13:59:06.518: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 304K, 8% free 8568K/9260K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
04-19 13:59:06.538: E/Google Maps Android API(26070): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
04-19 13:59:06.598: D/dalvikvm(26070): GC_CONCURRENT freed 381K, 8% free 8579K/9260K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 51ms
```

Comment: Did you check that the device can access the internet?

Comment: @tbkn Yes it can. Additionally, all location access permissions and whatnot are set to "on."

Comment: Is it an exception you see? Can you add logcat?

Comment: @tbkn Added to the body of the post.

Comment: might have to do with the API key. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727992/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers

Comment: @tbkn I've followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) to the letter and got the debug certificate fingerprint from there. Is that the correct one?

Comment: the guide you mentioned covers both release and debug certificates. Try using both of them and see if it helps.

Comment: Other than what everyone has mentioned, have you checked that Google API Console authorise the exact package you are using - `com.example.cs2110_final` (under "Key for Android apps")?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the correct services are enabled? Once I had a similar problem, and my issue was I accidentally enabled `Google Maps API v2` in place of `Google Maps Android API v2`.

Please check that you are enabled the correct Google map API service for android, which is `Google Maps Android API v2`.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks your problem is those two permissions:

```
 <permission
    android:name="com.example.cs2110_final.TheHunt.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.cs2110_final.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Which should be identical from the point of your package name, meaning if in one you wrote:

```
com.example.cs2110_final
```

which is your package name, then the second one should be the same, like that:

```
  <permission
    android:name="com.example.cs2110_final.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.cs2110_final.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

In addition make sure you are following all the steps of producing your API key, you can follow this guide I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Another problem I see in your code is the fact that you min target API version 8 (`android:minSdkVersion="8"`), So you should use the `SupportMapFragment` and `FragmentActivity` and not `MapFragment` and a simple `Activity` as you are doing right now. But as far as my knowledge goes this doesn't have to do anything with the problem you are having right now.

Still you will have to change it, you can follow this guide I wrote to do that:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)