# Displaying Map Using Google API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want to display map using google API. I am able to generate API key using debug.keystore but it shows only grid with label google not map i have added MapView control in xml file . what am i missing?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maptest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<permission
    android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true" />

</application>
```

Comment: In addition, I assume, you followed other steps on Google Maps API setup documentation?

Comment: please show the activity code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added a reference to the Google Play Services library to your project. See this guide [Google Maps Android v2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) for more further helps.

Comment: I have added Google Play Services library as reference in my project

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing some permission(s) in your Manifest, probably `MAPS_RECEIVE` or `READ_GSERVICES`. Check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727992/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers).

**Edit**: Insert your API key just before the closing tag `</application>`:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_api_key"/>
```

Add the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Delete these lines:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: I have added all permissinon regarding this

Comment: But i am using MapView control in activity_main.xml file and also provide API key in MapView control , how can i insert API key in Manifest file .

Comment: @user2289052 You didn't _clearly_ state from the beginning which API _version_ you were trying to use. Setting your API key in your `com.google.android.maps.MapView` layout element was needed for - now deprecated - Maps Android **v1** API. For Maps Android API **v2**, which is using `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`, you only need to add your API (v2) key in your Manifest. Please follow the official [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) for API v2. Also, if this answer solves your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you used Google android map in console and not Google Map. This might also be a problem. In addition to that another problem may be, you might have used map fragments. Use support Fragment in xml

android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

GoogleMap gm;

```
gm = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
```

Comment: using above code error is coming - The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: @user2289052 That error means your `MainActivity` extends `Activity` rather than `FragmentActivity` from [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).