# maps api v2 android. Stopped working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

I've had this app I made on my phone for a couple of weeks and it has been working fine until today. Everything in the console checks out fine except I get this:

08-07 10:31:03.110: I/Google Maps Android API(11207): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.

08-07 10:35:42.583: E/Google Maps Android API(11954): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

When I log into the google api console everything is green. I know its not the api key because it has been working in the past and the api console still says my key is good. Finally in my troubleshooting I can't seem to find any reason why the connection would be an issue as the internet is working fine both through the phone carrier and the wireless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those error-messages are normally a problem with the Google API-KEY. have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727992/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers), maybe you get some new information there.

Comment: Fantastic. I forgot I had reinstalled it from eclipse... Thanks

Comment: yeah, i had the same issue the last days. looked kinda familiar to see this error ;)