# Published google map not loading even after using production keystore

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-api-2

I have a app showing Google map. Previously i used debug keystore so it was working fine before releasing the app. I am having issue with loading the map when i use published app.

So following few answers i found out i should use sha1 created when i export the file that is,
[image]

This sha1 fingerprint i used to generate new Api key and put in `androidManifest.xml` file.

One more thing i have done, i think that might be the issue, previously i have used different google console account to create this api key now i am using different google account to generate it.

For example, previously i used abc@gmail.com account's google console to generate this Api key but now i have asked to use different gmail account. Does that make difference or else where could be the issue.

Comment: The key should be associated with the application.  It shouldn't matter once the key has been made as to which account uploads to the application to Google Play as I recall.

Comment: should i use both debug sha1 fingerprint as well production sha1 fingerprint to generate api key as i followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727992/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers but which api key should i put in manifest file.

Comment: I really don't recall needing anything related to the debug key for the actually launch of the release version.  Odd.  Really, only the release one should matter for any of the steps going forward in publishing your application.

Comment: In my eclipse i saw different SHA1 at Window>Preference>Android>build. SHA1 fingerprint there was one which i created using debug-keystore and not the SHA1 displaying in the above image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have production SHA1 keys registered in the developer console.

https://console.developers.google.com/
click your project then click credentials on the left.

Add the sha1 key to your project for public api access.
mutiple keys can be added for public api access separate with a return.

**You should have two maybe three keys for your project at most so this is not something you do with each release of the app.**

Comment: I have added production sha1 key by following above method.. But that is not working.

Comment: I have regenerated the Api key in Google console now and it is giving details of OBSOLETE KEY which probably is previous key. Still i am not able to get map.

Comment: I don't know what to do for you.  I haven't encountered the OBSOLETE KEY.